# Cocos2d-x 3.0 - DrawNode() for new class

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'll try to explain it as best as I can. I have to create a class of dots with their properties like dimension, color, sequences of actions and some bool, so I created a Dot.h file:

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
USING_NS_CC;
class Dot : public cocos2d::Layer{
public:
    virtual bool init();
    CREATE_FUNC(Whites);
private:
    bool circumstanceA = 1;
    bool circumstanceB = 0;
};
```

and a Dot.cpp file:

```
#include "Dot.h"
USING_NS_CC;
bool Dot::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
        return false;
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    auto scale = ScaleTo::create(0.5, (visibleSize.height / 6) + (arc4random() % (visibleSize.height / 15)) - visibleSize.height /30);
    auto scale_ease = EaseBackOut::create(scale->clone());
    return true;
}
```

Now, here's where I'm stuck. I'm new to Cocos2d-x syntax and kinda beginner as a programmer too, so if my question might seem banal to you I'm sorry, but I'm here to learn.

What I need is to be able to treat the objects from this class as they would be normal sprites.

First, how do I say the program that for every Dot object it must draw a dot to "append" to that object? Just like a sprite. Just adding something like

```
drawDot(Vec2((arc4random() % (int)(visibleSize.width - visibleSize.width / 6)) + visibleSize.width / 12, (arc4random() % (int)(visibleSize.width - visibleSize.width / 3.5)) + visibleSize.width / 7), 0, Color4F(255,255,255,255));
```

in the init() of Dot.cpp would be too simple :/

(Is the function I used for creating the dot the right one? I've found many around the net but couldn't tell which one is the best/latest...)

Should I do it in my scene when I declare a new object? Like

```
Dot *myDot = Dot::create();
myDot->drawDot(Vec2((arc4random() % (int)(visibleSize.width - visibleSize.width / 6)) + visibleSize.width / 12, (arc4random() % (int)(visibleSize.width - visibleSize.width / 3.5)) + visibleSize.width / 7), 0, Color4F(255,255,255,255));
```

But in this way it won't compile...

I need a base to start on, please tell me if I'm going the right way or if I have to restart in a different way in order to get my dot objects...

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake here:

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-properly-subclass-drawnode/19090

I just had to replace the implementation in the class declaration in Dot.h

From

```
class Dot : public cocos2d::Layer
```

to

```
class Dot : public cocos2d::DrawNode
```

Thanks anyway! :)